# Keycloak Connection Refused on login

Tags: nginx, keycloak

I am running keycloak from docker and i have nginx as a reverse proxy.
here is my keycloak config:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
    command:
      [
        '-b',
        '0.0.0.0',
        # by default fresh realm will be imported on restart.   if you need to keep
        # this data longer comment out following 4 lines
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING',
        '-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000',
        '-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled',
      ]
    volumes:
      #  enable this volume for persistent database otherwise keycloak db will be always created fresh
      #- ./keycloak-db:/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data
      - ./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=h2
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      - 10990:10990
```

and my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen        443;
    server_name   keycloak.myserver.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/myserver.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/sslmyserver.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    proxy_set_header        Host $host:8443;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9080;
    }
}
```

When i try to access keycloak in browser: keycloak.myserver.com i am redirected to keycloak.myserver.com/auth and everything works cert is valid and everything looks ok. Now when i try to access the Administration Console i am redirected to keycloak.myserver.com:8443/auth/admin

i get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED no errors shown on nginx logs neither on docker logs for keycloak. any help would be appreciated.

firewall is allowing all communication on 8443, 443, 9080 etc..

Answer (score 0):

If someone went through something similar.

```
proxy_set_header        Host $host:8443;
```

this was the issue, changing it to `proxy_set_header        Host $host;` fixed the issue and everything now works.